# Win 10, search file with date created in date range and type of file pdf

Tags: windows-10, search, date, file-types, range

On Windows 10, I would like to search for file which was created between 2/1/2018 and 3/1/2018 and has extention .pdf?

I know how to search for certain date range, but do not know how to add extension search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for a file extension by using the * wildcard, so add `*.pdf` to your search.

e.g. to search for pdf files created in between 1st and 31st Jan 2019 i would use:
`*.pdf modified:1/1/2019 .. 31/01/2019`

Comment: Thank you, so how do I enter both date and type search?

Comment: Answer updated with an example